# multiple changes on <a> tag

Tags: css, html

I've been having this problem for a while now. I want to change the look of the "li a". I want one li a tag on one thing, and another and a second thing, but I can only change it once, then it will look like that on all the other places I used it, for example the . Sorry for explaining this so poorly. I have no idea what I'm talking about. Hope someone understands.

Comment: Could you be more specific? and clear.. maybe adding some code will help explain yourself

Comment: just add your code here

Comment: Add your code in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try this

target all the even/uneven list-items

```
li:nth-of-type(even)
```

target a specific iteration. In this example you target every third item.

```
li:nth-of-type(n+2n)
```

target a specific number

```
li:nth-of-type(4)
```